# Are syntax corrections valid edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I just got the pleasure to *attempt* to review [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5017688).

It was a syntax correction, but was incorrect anyways (I *think*), so I was going to reject it. Well, it turns out other reviewers beat me to it by about 2 seconds (I didn't even get to submit my review), so it was approved.

There were two reviewers who *did* get a chance to review the suggested edit that rejected it for similar reasons to mine. So I [rolled back the now approved edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10828337/revisions).

Did I do the right thing?

**And in general, are syntax corrections valid edits?**

Comment: Sorry for being a fun-hater, but that tag... no, no.

Comment: @Matt How about [did-i-mess-up]

Comment: @Matt fun-hater on meta? Nothing makes sense anymore

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It was a syntax correction, but was incorrect anyways (***I think***), so I was going to reject it.

## ... so skip it.

---

*In general*, a *correct* syntax correction on an answer is fine. An invalid syntax correction, obviously, is not.

If you see a suggested edit which *breaks* a posts syntax, you should act as you should do with *any* invalid edit, and roll it back.

Syntax corrections to *questions* are an entirely different kettle of fish, as the syntax error is usually the cause of the question itself. These should almost always be rejected.

---

<sup>Specifically to this question, [`String.length()` is correct](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_length.htm), [as is `String.substring()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm), so this suggested edit was correct.</sup>

Comment: I think I actually misread the code as _javascript_, in which `length` isn't a function.

Comment: @SantaClaus: Regardless of this particular case; if you see an edit which you aren't sure about, *please* ***skip it*** rather than guessing!

Comment: Here's something I thought of that jumps off of this question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259960/should-suggested-edit-reviewers-be-limited-to-those-questions-in-tags-they-are-a

Answer (score 4):

Yes, an edit that breaks the code in an answer should most certainly be rolled back.  It's also probably worth flagging the post and informing the moderators that this incorrect edit had been approved, as this is a sign that these reviewers aren't paying attention and may need a break from reviewing.

Comment: Apparently people think that an edit that breaks code in an answer shouldn't be rolled back...