# Should suggested edit reviewers be limited to those questions in tags they are active in?

Tags: discussion

Since [syntax corrections are valid edits to answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259958/2446155), should suggested edit reviewers be limited to those questions in tags they are active in?

A few of us innocent reviewers came upon [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5017688), and with not many of us having much [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) experience, some of us wanted to reject the edit. (I actually misread it as *javascript*, and therefore thought the edit was invalid)

***If I came upon an edit that claimed to edit syntax of a language that I wasn't familiar at all with, how could I effectively review that edit?***

Comment: What is wrong with Skip?

Comment: @rene Skip is an amazing tool, but not all users would make use of Skip in that situation. I'm asking if users are really qualified to review an edit that changes syntax of a language they are not active in.

Comment: Same thing as other review queues, if you are not familiar enough with the subject matter at hand to make an educated response on the review then skip it and leave it for people who are more knowledge with the topics in question.

Comment: I guess the question would be is "how do you determine activity?" Just because a poster is not active in a tag doesn't mean that (s)he doesn't know the syntax for whatever reason.

Comment: Why would we limit reviewers if suggesters aren't limited in the same way?

Comment: @JoshCaswell suggesters do not make a decision, reviewers do that.

Comment: @g24l, how is _choosing what_ to edit and _in what manner_ not making decisions?

Comment: @JoshCaswell suggesters do not make a decision *on what is finally displayed*, **reviewers do that**. Of course suggesters ( maybe editor is a more appropriate term) can decide what shocks to wear, but that is irrelevant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Most* suggested edits don't require expertise in the tag to judge whether or not the edit is appropriate, as such requiring a given score for a tag wouldn't be productive.  On the odd occasion that you come across a suggested edit that you don't have the expertise to judge the validity of, you can skip it yourself.

The suggested edit queue *already* is written to attempt to give you edits in tags that your active in, when it has a choice, to mitigate the issue, but due to the fact that the queue is generally not that large, it's not uncommon for there to *be* no suggested edits in tags you're active in, in which case it will then resort to showing you edits from other tags (which you still have a reasonable chance of evaluating) rather than giving you nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Arguably many suggested edits don't necessarily require expertise related to the tag to judge. Other edits do require such expertise, [here is an example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313448/should-reviews-be-directed-to-users-active-on-the-respective-tag).

I would suggest to disambiguate between those that require "*expert per tag reviewers*" by parsing the edit. For example if it affects code in the post then it could be processed by experts associated with the tags.

Comment: Most even of those edits don't need an expert, just someone with superficial familiarity and/or a modicum of common sense. The latter is not common though...

Comment: @Deduplicator true, sadly common sense is a non occurring statistical ideal.