# When is it appropriate to edit?

Tags: support, edits, editing-help

There have been a number of questions I have edited (many of them first posts or first answers) and I find myself doing a lot of grammar or spelling edits. Frequently I add an edit for "clarification", meaning I arrange the sentence structure so that it reads more easily (to me at least)

an example: "im gettin message random error message 1234"

gets changed to:

I'm receiving the following error message

```
random error message 1234
```

I think this helps the user gets their point across more clearly and will help them receive a helpful answer, however I also feel like I might be cheating the system to get the +2 reputation from editing. So my question is this:

At what point is it appropriate to rearrange (and to correct, in my opinion) a user's question in the manner I described above?

tl;dr: I feel like I'm cheating the system with unnecessary edits sometimes, when is it appropriate to edit a question?

Comment: If an edit does not change "i" to "I" (does not capitalize the first personal pronoun), I usually reject it as "too minor".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is appropriate to edit a question when you do in fact improve the question. If for example you do just correct 3 spelling errors, but another 10 remain I would reject the edit as "too minor".

If you do feel like you do not improve the post you have edited, then you should probably not do it.

Personally when I come across some syntax errors ("i" vs "I" or similar), I tend to fix the grammar. But all of it.

[Somehow related to this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259956/are-syntax-corrections-valid-edits), [that aswell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251926/is-it-appropriate-to-edit-a-question-for-grammar-style-formatting?rq=1)

[This does provide a very good answer too.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code?rq=1)

Comment: This makes good sense