# Why my edit was rejected as 'trying to address author'?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I recently suggested an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6958609) to question and it was rejected with the following explanation:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer

Thing is all I did was:

1. improve spelling & grammar
2. removed *totally unimportant* code parts for brevity
3. merged three blocks into one long block

My question is not only about why it was rejected, but why with such reason?
I don't see why or *how* it could be expressed as comment / answer?

Comment: It would appear that the reviewers didn't feel that the code you removed was in fact superfluous.  My initial reaction when looking at the edit is that I'd agree with them.

Comment: *Maybe* because you edited parts of the code that would have best been left in there?  The grammar changes are solid, at least.

Comment: @Makoto Maybe you're right, but then why such (unfit?) explanation? Shouldn't it be 'destructive edit'?

Comment: Good question.  I'm guessing it may have been groupthink at that point; they saw that they should have rejected this particular edit, but believed that everyone else had got the rejection reason right.

Comment: I feel like these are the same people who would flag short answers as "not an answer" and answer "why" questions with "here's a workaround".

Comment: @BoltClock To be fair, none of the reasons here fit all that well.  They didn't choose the best option, but there was not particularly great option.  It almost needs a custom reason, and of course there's a strong pull to using a canned reason over a custom one.

Comment: @Servy Hmm, isn't there 'destructive edit' reason that describes exactly this case? Removing crucial part of question?

Comment: @joozek There's a reason for spam or vandalism.  This edit doesn't look like intentional vandalism to me.  There's a "conflicts with the author's intent" which is not exactly quite right either, although it's closer.  Really I don't see any of them fitting; I'd probably have gone with a custom reason myself.

Comment: @Servy What do you think I should do next time? Two separate edits with grammar/spelling and code-cleaning? I still believe that code was unnecessary and unimportant code makes questions harder to read

Comment: @joozek You should be vary wary of editing code in questions.  While it's not universally prohibited from touching it in entirety, you need to be very careful that you aren't doing anything that would cause the code to no longer replicate the problem described, to have other problems not described, or (as was probably the case here) to make an edit that reviewers are simply unsure about whether it affects the code's execution.  I suspect the reviewers were being conservative; since they didn't *know* that the removed code was completely superfluous, they didn't feel comfortable removing it.

Comment: @BoltClock: The suggestion was properly rejected (it nearly slipped through), even though the *reason* given was a puzzler.

Comment: The reject reason is probably misleading as to the reviewers' thought process. What I'd guess happened is the first person saw your addition of "but they all result in 401 Unauthorized" and thought that was an attempt to respond because they didn't scroll down (i.e. a wrongful reject); the other two chose the same thing because it was already highlighted and they were going to reject it anyway for broader reasons.

Comment: @Leushenko: No, the first person saw the comment: "corrected spelling, fixed grammar, improved formatting. Made things a little bit clearer" and a considerable deletion of code. No one complained that this was too much code. The question is unanswered since 26 days. One should try to answer the question rather than to correct it!

Comment: @rkhb Improving question improves chances of someone reading it and consecutively answering it, you know.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your edit was really good, but it had one *fatal flaw*.

While removing redundancy and irrelevant parts from the code-examples (which in and of itself is actually a *good* thing), **you removed a difference between the first and the other two tries**:
The URL used changes, only for the first one using embedded credentials.

Anyway, why didn't you take the opportunity to properly (which means consistently) format *all* the code, a far less error-prone endeavour, while you were at it?

Thus, I used your non-code-changes as a basis for improving the post.

Comment: It's good you edited the question after all

Answer (score 36):

Usually, you should avoid edits to code, *especially in questions*. I'd recommend reading "[When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/359284)" for more information about why.

> 1. improve spelling & grammar

This looks good, and [we generally appreciate spelling and grammar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251928/359284) edits. You'll find that, for the most part, edits containing only spelling and grammar edits will be approved. The one exception to this is if there are only a few, or it's clear that there are [other edits that should have been made](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/263111/359284).

One of the glaring edits I see that was missing was the formatting of the code blocks, which are clearly indented way too far. Most likely it was copied and pasted from an editor and the formatting was not fixed, **but formatting is something you can easily fix.**

> 2. removed totally unimportant code parts for brevity

This can sometimes be OK in answers if it's clear that the code can be removed, and your suggested edit tries to explain *why they were removed*. But questions are special, because editing code in questions has a tendency to invalidate answers. It's common for question edits to change code to be rejected with the reason you were given because we feel that it's better to **leave a comment and let the question asker make the edit**.

I personally wouldn't have made this edit, so I can't think of a comment you could have used.

> 3. merged three blocks into one long block

I have mixed feelings about this. In some cases, combining code blocks makes it more difficult to follow the questions. But quite often, it makes it more difficult to follow because *you typically don't see it happen* and you don't know right away why there are three similar blocks of code next to each other. I personally would skip the edit review if it was just this, but others would very likely reject it for having no improvement.

Comment: This is the correct answer. His non code changes were really good. But his code changes were blatant wrong, that means the edit itself is wrong. Just like you, I am not an advocate of combining code blocks in to one. I always prefer to have 3 different blocks if these blocks are different. Anything to avoid disgusting horizontal/vertical scrollbars.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: Too bad you can't half-reject an edit request, eh?

Comment: @SamB You can "Improve" and replace the code with the source from the previous revision. Or, from the other direction, copy source from the suggestion and "Reject and Edit" implementing only part of the suggestion,  if you are feeling punitive.

Comment: @AirThomas: Yeah, I know you can do those, and I guess "Reject and Edit" at least captures that editing was a good idea but that there was something wrong with the actual edit... but at times like these, a button halfway between the two would seem more appropriate.  Not really a serious suggestion though :-).